# Does WPF have a control for browsing the local file system?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to add a control to my app where the user can browse his local file system and select a directory.  I would prefer to host this control on my main app window, and not do this via a pop-up dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one built in.

You can either use the WinForms file/folder browser, search [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=3403571#_comments) or similar site for someone else's implementation or write your own.

I've found one on [Ookii Dialogs](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf) that includes some other standard dialogs.

Comment: @kenny - If you're talking about Ookii I don't know. I can't see anything on the site that specifies a license, but there is one in the download. You can use and redistribute as long as you keep the current attributions etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host the controls on your own form, use controls from [Shell MegaPack.WPF](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm)